# Gmail image map - only the last area works

Tags: html, gmail, imagemap

I'm creating an HTML email using a large image with an image map, which has two rectangle areas specified:

```
<img src="newsletter_files/background.jpg" width="600" height="584" border="0" alt="39steps crimbo cards" usemap="#email">

<map name="email">
<area shape="rect" name="emailaddress" coords="212,305,350,290" href="mailto:email@domain.com" alt="Email email@domain.com" />
<area shape="rect" name="website" coords="585,485,465,550" href="http://www.domain.co.uk" target="_blank" alt="Domain link" />
</map>
```

Trouble is, only the second one works. The first one is ignored. I've Googled for solutions but not found anything.

I could cut the image up but that creates its own problems with testing etc - the email is very simple so for my purposes an image map is the best method.

Anybody had similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't about image maps in emails (mostly because I've never used them)

What I suggest is open the image in photoshop and use the slice tool. When you save you can save images and `html`. The html outputted will be perfect for emails.

A couple other things when it comes to html emails:

- ALWAYS use tables
- NEVER use `p` tags
- always put `display:block` on your images (this prevents unwanted gaps between images on some email clients

Comment: Thank you. photoshop simplified all process.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with your image-map. The first link is ignored because it's a mailto: call. Gmail strips the href out of a link if it contains a mailto:

Answer (score 0):

I just read something interesting from Constant Contact. here is what it said:

In a custom HTML email, if an image map tag exists, and the hyperlink is to a mailto: link, if the tag is closed like the following example...

```
    <area shape="rect" coords="88,23,166,38" href="mailto:info@constantcontact.com"/>
```

...the hyperlink will be inactive. Simply removing the closing forward slash will make the link active again.

• Leaving a closing forward slash in a normal hyperlink to a URL will work in a custom HTML email.

• Leaving a closing forward slash after a mailto: link in a custom XHTML email will work.
But -

• Leaving a closing forward slash after a mailto: link in a custom HTML email will NOT work.

Comment: Interesting but not working. Seems looking at the source shows that gmail indeed strips the href away as @Eric mentioned (slash or not).